# jQuery addClass function not working on site

Tags: jquery, css-animations

I'm creating a website that requires a quick animation of a truck to drive across the screen once the document is ready.

markup:

```
<div id="truck">
    <img src="<?php directory() ?>/images/truck.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#truck {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

#truck img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100%;
  right: -100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 9;
}

#truck.drive img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: 100%;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#truck').addClass('drive');
});
```

So this seems like it's working when I plug it into a codepen: https://codepen.io/ericbrockman/pen/ZEYyQJe

but when I try to use it on the site I'm creating, the div with the ID truck doesn't get the class "drive" added to it on document ready. Both the jQuery I wrote and the jQuery library are being loaded to the DOM as resources.

live site: http://cyb3rtruck.com

Any help figuring this out would be, as always, greatly appreciated!
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
   $('#truck').addClass('drive');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the distribution of jQuery that you're using doesn't assign the `jQuery` function to `$`. So just set it before your `$( document ).ready` function.

```
var $ = jQuery;
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#truck').addClass('drive');
});
```

Comment: no luck, unfortunately. I am running this though `(function($) {.....});` shouldn't that take care of assigning the `$`? Either way, adding `var $ = jQuery;` before the block of code didn't work.

Comment: @EricBrockman Try `(function(jQuery) {.....});` and also `var $ = jQuery;` inside

Comment: try this one `jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
  $('#truck').addClass('drive');
});`

Comment: @Rob Kwasowski still no dice.

Comment: @Akbar Ali for the win! If you can leave your comment as an answer I will accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery isn't assigned to the '$' variable